# Making an int input subtracted by 1(python)

Tags: python

For some reason this does not work:

```
print("Enter your number")
x=input("") #This is yo make the input on the next line
x==x-1
print(x)
```

This is a basic view of what I'm actually doing.
**note**I have tried putting int at every point of this program and have even tried giving x a previously assigned value of 0

Comment: `==` is equality comparison, not assignment (which is `=`). You could just do `x -= 1`.

Comment: 1) `input` returns a string, so you have to convert it with `int()` or `float()` into a number. 2) `a = 2` assigns a value, `a == 2` compares two values, `a -= 1` subtracts a value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
print("Print your Number")
num = int(input(""))
num -= 1
print(num)
```

Comment: Thanks. This site is really helpful

Comment: I just wanted to know, as this was all purposed to remove an item from a list, if I cold reder a list value invisible when viewing it, but still there in the code.

Comment: I put a number next to each of the items in a list starting from 1 onwards, and because lists start from 0 I had to subtract 1 from the user input so that they select the right one. What my code does is turn that code into a blank ("") so that if they want to add something to the list I will make sure that it gets filled. However, my code also allows people to view the list and it ends up like this 'a','','c','d'. Is there any way to make it invisible to the user

Answer (score 1):

Two things are wrong with your code:

- You're treating `x` as an integer without casting it. When you take input from the `input` function, the returned value is a string. To cast it into an integer, use the `int` function.
- `==` is used for comparison. Assignment (giving a value to a variable) only takes one `=`.

Your code should thus be the following:

```
print("Enter your number")
x = int(input(""))
x = x - 1
print(x)
```